# Can two wizards use Leomund's secret chest to transport items between vast distances?

Tags: dnd-5e

[Related to this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167499/what-happens-if-2-wizards-cast-secret-chest-on-the-same-chest). Assuming that two wizards cast [Leomund's Secret Chest](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/secret-chest) on the same chest and then go in different directions could they use this chest to exchange items over vast distances? To clarify a bit.

1- Wizard A and Wizard B cast Leomund's secret chest on the same chest.

2. Wizard A leaves to venture into a dungeon while Wizard B stays at the
   city.
3. Wizard A finds a huge hoard of gold but cannot carry it. Using
   sending to reach Wizard B he asks Wizard B to summon their chest
   every five minutes and dump it's contents.
4. Wizard A summons the chest    and fills the empty chest with gold.
   Sends it to Ethereal Plane
5. Wizard B summons the chest and empties the content before sending it
   to Ethereal Plane Rinse and repeat till the entire hoard is taken
   back to the city within the span of an hour.

Answer (score 4):

**No**

> COMBINING MAGICAL EFFECTS (PHB pg 205)
>
> The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap. **The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don’t combine, however.** Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap.
>
> For example, if two clerics cast bless on the same target, that character gains the spell’s benefit only once; he or she doesn’t get to roll two bonus dice.

The second casting of the spell on the chest would replace the first or do nothing, depending on the characters doing the casting and, quite possibly, DM fiat.